# ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file (Error code :13)

Tags: linux, mysql, sql

Iam trying to create a mysql table in linux with changing data directory to another location. The selected forlder having full permission. But I got an error 'Can't create/write to file'. I googled and found that this error related to permission denied. I can change the owner permission of the folder to root using chown command. But it still showing the same error.

```
mysql> create table table123(Id int PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20)) DATA DIRECTORY = '/home/test/Sample';

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/test/Sample/table123.MYD' (Errcode: 13)
```

When change the data directory location to `/var/tmp/Sample`, then the table become created.

Why the table not created in the location `'/home/test/Sample'` ???

```
Using ubuntu 10.04.
Permission of actual data directory is 700, owner : mysql, group : mysql
```

Comment: Write some more info, system, distro, mysql version  permision and owner of actual data directory

Answer (score 2):

You should change owner of new location to mysql user (`chown mysql.mysql /data/directory`). In simple copy owner ond permision from actual data directory.

EDIT:
Set up permision on new data directory using `chmod 755 /data/directory`

Comment: I don't know how to copy ownership and permission. Can u explain the same please?

Comment: By copy I meant see what ownership has actual data directory (using `ls -la`) and set up the same on new data directory but its on 100% taht data directory should bed owned by user mysql. Then setup same permisions with chmod on new data directory as actual data direcory has. Sorry my english is not good, I can't write it simpler

Comment: But shows the same error, after setting the owner and permission of new data dir as same as of actual datadir.

Comment: Show what owner ond permision has actual data directory

Comment: `drwx------  4 mysql         mysql         4096 2012-10-08 16:16 mysql` - actual data directory.                                                                                                                                                                                           `drwx------  3 mysql mysql  4096 2012-10-09 12:08 Sample` - new data directory

Comment: >> Why the table not created in the location '/home/test/Sample' ???                         CMIIW because the user directory usually set 700. so no matter you change permissions on /home/test/*, the parent permission is still 700 unless you change chmod 755 -R /home/test                                                           # useradd testuser
# ls -alh /home/
drwx------  3 testuser testuser 4.0K Oct  9 09:00 testuser